# Specify which maven build plugins to use in a parent pom

Tags: maven

I have a couple of projects, all using the same plugins in the build section.
Is it possible to specify which plugins to run inside the build section in a central place?

I know you can put the plugin configuration in a parent poms pluginManagement section, but then you still have to list all plugins in the build section.

For example I want something like:

parent.pom

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>plugin1</artifactId>
      ...
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>plugin2</artifactId>
      ...
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

child.pom

```
<build>
    <include-plugins-from-parent-without-listing-plugin1-and-plugin2/>
</build>
```

Also, I would like to do the same thing with reports. Define in a single file which reports to run and include this in every other project.

Update: any other way of synchronizing the same build settings between multiple projects is fine too. I just do not want to copy&paste the same stuff in all POM files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside parent.pom declare the plugins inside `<build>\<plugins>` instead of `<pluginManagement>`:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>plugin1</artifactId>
      ...
    </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: This results in executing those plugins during the release of the parent pom which is not what is intended.

Comment: I though if this, but it has problems like khmarbaise says

Comment: Well, I never heard of any other way and don´t know if it is possible.

Comment: I am accepting this answer because it seems this is the only method possible using Maven. For my project I started preprocessing the pom files to avoid copy&paste the same stuff in many files.